# Need an Explanantion

Tags: measure-theory

I hope someone could spend some seconds to help me understanding this paragraph.
 The paper by Von Neumann:

This part is little bit confusing for me

> Let $E$ be a set of positive measure which contains no measurable subsets of smaller positive measure. It follows that for each $n$ one of the two sets, **$EA_n$**, and $E(X-A_n)$ has measure zero and the other one has measure $m(E)$.

My question is : what does this notation $EA_n$ mean, and the main idea of this part

This is the reference

[The Neumann Compendium, p.146](https://books.google.com/books?id=MY2_V2BfP5cC&pg=PA146lpg=PA146&q=%22Let%20E%20be%20a%20set%20of%20positive%22)

Comment: I think somtimes instead of writing $A \cap B$, some authors write $AB$, for sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means $E \cap A_n$.  You may have heard some people talk about "set algebra" or "Boolean algebra".  It's possible to interpret set operations as an algebra with $A + B = A\cup B$ and $A\times B = A\cap B$.  (The comutitivity, transitivity and distributivity properties all still hold).

If you replace $EA_n$ with $E\cap A_n$  and $E(X-A_n)$ with $E\cap (X_n - A_n)$ the meaning should be clearer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks alot yes I have heard about Set algebra and Boolean algebra.